# Kendo ScrollView can't read from Local dataSource

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I'm trying to attach a local dataSource to Kendo Scrollview widget, but I'm having difficulty getting it to work.

The scrollView initializes properly, but unable to read from the dataSource.

```
<div id="scrollView" data-role="scrollview"></div>

var localArray = [{
  name: "John"
}, {
  name: "Doe"
}, ];

$("#scrollView").kendoMobileScrollView({
  dataSource: localArray,
  template: $("#kendo-template").html(),
  contentHeight: 115
});
```

However, if I use the setDataSource method, it works just fine:

```
<div id="scrollView" data-role="scrollview" data-template="kendo-template"></div>

$("#accountCardScroller").data("kendoMobileScrollView").setDataSource(localArray);
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I force the scrollView widget to fetch from the dataSource?

Answer (score 0):

That sort of sounds like a bug to me. Maybe try this instead, which will turn the array into a `DataSource` first:

```
var localArray = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [{
        name: "John"
    }, {
        name: "Doe"
    }]
});
```

Comment: I tried this, still doesn't work, but if I pass localArray (constructed using DS), it works.